# What is the best way to organize headers in C++?

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm looking for the most portable and most organized way to include headers in C++. I'm making a game, and right now, my project structure looks like this:

```
game
| util
| | foo.cpp
| | foo.h
| ...
game-client
| main.cpp
| graphics
| | gfx.cpp
| | gfx.h
| ...
game-server
| main.cpp
| ...
```

Say I want to include foo.h from gfx.cpp. As far as I know, there are 3 ways to do this:

1. `#include "../../game/util/foo.h`. This is what I'm currently doing, but it gets messier the deeper into the folder structure I go.
2. `#include "foo.h"`. My editor (Xcode) compiles fine with just this, but I'm not sure about other compilers.
3. `#include "game/util/foo.h"`, and adding the base directory to the include path.

Which one is the best? (most portable, most organized, scales the best with many folders, etc.)

Comment: _The best_ looks opinion based. Possibly you'd like to ask about advantages or disadvantages of different approaches instead.

Comment: I've become a fan of separating the headers that expose a public interface into their own folder for easy packaging of libraries. This means I use lot of option 3.

Answer (score 4):

I found the below approach most useful when you are dealing with a large code base.

1. Public headers

> `module_name/include/module_name/public_header.hpp`
>
> `module_name/include/module_name/my_class.hpp`
>
> `...`

2. Private headers and source

> ```
> module_name/src/something_private.cpp  
> module_name/src/something_private.hpp 
> module_name/src/my_class.cpp
> ```

Notes:

- **module_name** is repeated to ensure that the module name is provided    while including a public header from this library/module.
  This    improves the readability and also avoids extra time spent to
  find the    location of the header when same name is used in multiple
  modules.